# Terraform applying huge index value for instance EBS block store

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terragrunt

I am using Terraform (called via Terragrunt, if that's relevant) to create an instance from an AMI and mount an existing volume:

```
resource "aws_instance" "jenkins_master_with_snap" {
    count                   = "${var.master_with_snapshot}"
    ami                     = "${var.jenkins_ami}"
    instance_type           = "${var.jenkins_instance_type}"
    iam_instance_profile    = "${data.terraform_remote_state.global.jenkins_profile_name}"
    subnet_id               = "${data.aws_subnet.jenkins_subnet_with_snap.id}"
    key_name                = "${var.key_name}"
    vpc_security_group_ids  = [
        "${aws_security_group.jenkins_master_target_sg.id}",
        "${data.terraform_remote_state.cicd.cicd_sg_ipa}"
    ]

    ebs_block_device {
        snapshot_id = "${var.master_snapshot_id}"
        device_name = "${var.jenkins_volume_device}"
        volume_type = "gp2"
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that the AMI used to create this resource already has a snapshot mapped to it from the build process, so this resource basically just replaces it with a different snapshot. I'm not sure if this is why I'm having the problem or not.

I'm using the resulting resource attributes to populate a Python template that will be zipped and uploaded as a lambda function.  The Python script requires the `volume-id` from this instance's EBS block device.

```
data "template_file" "ebs_backup_lambda_with_snapshot_template" {
    count       = "${var.master_with_snapshot}"
    template    = "${file("${path.module}/jenkins_lambda_ebs_backup.py.tpl")}"

    vars {
        volume_id = "${aws_instance.jenkins_master_with_snap.ebs_block_device.???.volume_id}"
    }
}
```

Onto the actual problem: I do not know how to properly reference the volume ID in the `vars` section of the `template_file` resource above.  Here is the resulting state:

```
ebs_block_device.#                                = 1
ebs_block_device.1440725774.delete_on_termination = true
ebs_block_device.1440725774.device_name           = /dev/xvdf
ebs_block_device.1440725774.encrypted             = true
ebs_block_device.1440725774.iops                  = 900
ebs_block_device.1440725774.snapshot_id           = snap-1111111111111
ebs_block_device.1440725774.volume_id             = vol-1111111111111
ebs_block_device.1440725774.volume_size           = 300
ebs_block_device.1440725774.volume_type           = gp2
ebs_optimized                                     = false
root_block_device.#                               = 1
root_block_device.0.delete_on_termination         = false
root_block_device.0.iops                          = 0
root_block_device.0.volume_id                     = vol-1111111111111
root_block_device.0.volume_size                   = 8
root_block_device.0.volume_type                   = standard
```

The problem is that the index for the EBS volume is that insane integer `1440725774`. I have no idea why that is occuring.  In the console, there's only a single map in the list I'm interested in:

```
> aws_instance.jenkins_master_with_snap.ebs_block_device
[
  {    delete_on_termination = 1  device_name = /dev/xvdf  encrypted = 1  iops = 900  snapshot_id = snap-1111111111111  volume_id = vol-1111111111111  volume_size = 300  volume_type = gp2}
]
```

And it appears the only way to reference any of those keys is to use that index value directly:

```
> aws_instance.jenkins_master_with_snap.ebs_block_device.1440725774.volume_id
vol-1111111111111
```

Is there any way to reliably reference a single element in a list like this when I have no idea what the index is going to be? I can't just hardcode that integer into the `template_file` resource above and assume it's going to be the same every time. Does anyone have any clues as to why this is occurring in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps instead of inlining [ebs_block_device](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#ebs_block_device) block, create a separate [aws_ebs_volume](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ebs_volume.html) resource, then attach it with an [aws_volume_attachment](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/volume_attachment.html). Then reference the `aws_ebs_volume.name.id` attribute to get the ID you need.

Example (extended from the [example code](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/volume_attachment.html#example-usage) in `aws_volume_attachment`):

```
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "ebs_att" {
  device_name = "/dev/sdh"
  volume_id   = "${aws_ebs_volume.example.id}"
  instance_id = "${aws_instance.web.id}"
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami               = "ami-21f78e11"
  availability_zone = "us-west-2a"
  instance_type     = "t1.micro"
  tags {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }

  subnet_id = "<REDACTED>"
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "example" {
  availability_zone = "us-west-2a"
  size              = 1
}

data "template_file" "example" {
    template    = "Your volume ID is $${volume_id}"

    vars {
     volume_id = "${aws_ebs_volume.example.id}"
    }
}

output "custom_template" {
  value = "${data.template_file.example.rendered}"
}
```

The resultant output:

```
Outputs:

custom_template = Your volume ID is vol-0b1064d4ca6f89a15
```

You can then use `${aws_ebs_volume.example.id}` in your template vars to populate your lambda.

Comment: I think this is a fine answer.  Thanks for taking the time. However, what I actually ended up doing to save time for now was to just pass the instance ID and derive the volume ID needed from within the lambda with boto3.  I will probably implement this solution or similar in the future.